# How to use proxy in webpack and reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, webpack-dev-server

I have added following code in "webpack.config.dev.js"

```
devServer: {
    proxy:{
        target:"http://localhost:8081"
    }
}
```

I'm using following axios code, but it's not taking proxy as a url

```
axios({
    method:"post",
    url:"/add_order_product",
    data:result
}).then(response =>{
    alert(response.data);
    if(response.data === true){
        // console.log(response);
        alert("saving data");
    }
}).catch(response =>{
    console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default webpack-dev-server does not enable root proxying. In order to enable root proxying, the `index` property needs to be set to a falsy value. Their documentation also has the `context` property set, although they don't explicitly say that it is need for root proxying. Try the configuration below, and [here's a link](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy) to the webpack-dev-server proxy documentation.

```
devServer: {
    index: '',
    proxy: {
        context: () => true,
        target: "http://localhost:8081"
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with your solution provided above, but it's not working it still giving 404 error (not connecting to the proxy server).

Comment: What does your API server / routes look like? Is '/add_order_product' a valid route?

Comment: Yes, it's a valid route. When I try to connect http://localhost:8081/add_order_product its connecting but when I try to connect with the proxy it's not getting connected.